# Finding Consecutive numbers From a Arithmetic series in an Array of random numbers

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I had an exam question asking the solution to find how many consecutive numbers in the arithmetic series n, n*2, n*3, n*i ( where i is array length - 1 ) are in an array of random numbers.  The numbers from the series can be in any order in the array as long as you start from n and the numbers are consecutive.  Repeats are allowed.

For example: n = 2 and your array is [ 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 6, 10 ]

would return 3.  Since the longest consecutive run starting with 2 is 2, 4, 6.

The solution I proposed was to transform the above array into [ 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 5 ] by dividing numbers divisible by n ( 2 ) by n and changing numbers which are not modulo n to 0.

I then quicksort the array into [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 ] and do a linear check to find the answer.

This gives me a solution which is 2n + n log n or O( n log n ).

Is there a better solution to this problem?  I mean an order of magnitude better, like O( n ).

Comment: You seem to be talking about an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) rather than a [gemoetric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), right?

Comment: Note that using your own nomenclature, your solution is O(i log i), not O(n log n).

Comment: You're right about it being arithmetic, wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An O(i) solution using additional storage space would be to use a bit vector of size i initialised to 0.  Iterate through the array and set the entry j to one if you encounter n*j.  After that, find the number of ones at the beginning of the bit vector.

Comment: Needs to be at least O(n) ... You need to walk through the whole array anyway. Worst case scenario is that 2 4 6 are in the end of the array. (think of a million numbers followed by 2 4 6...)

Comment: @Yochai Sven said it was O(n), that's an `i` there not a `1`.

Comment: @Yochai:  Strangely, the OP calls the number of elements in the array i, not n, and n is the common difference of the arithmetic progression.  So this is O(i), not O(n).

Comment: @Sven Marnach:  Got it to work for n = 1, then realized that negative numbers anywhere in the process screw it up.  So your solution works for all positive numbers.

Comment: @Robert: What's the problem with negative numbers?  I don't see any.

Comment: @Robert: If you want to support negative numbers, you obviously will have to check for them, just as you do check for numbers bigger than `num * a.length`.  You will have to define the exact behaviour you wish for negative numbers and implement it -- your post is not entirely clear about how to handle them.  I proposed a fix in the pastebin (but note that I don't know Java).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a reasonable and known bound on the range of values, you could use a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) to reduce the complexity to O(n) (or O(i) in your terms).

Comment: There is no bound on the range of values.

Comment: In which case you'd need a massive array and counting sort wouldn't be memory-efficient. Have a look at Sven's solution, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You started good. Loop through the array and set each array cell **Aj** to **Aj/n** .

Make a bit array of length **i-1** ( you have **i-1** number ).

Set them all to zeros.

Loop through the array again, for each number you encounter (**k**) set bit **k** (if it's less than **m**) to 1.

Loop through the bit array from place 1, and stop at the first zero. That's the result.

You got about **4*i** Iterations ... **O(i)**